# Dataframe format change, I want to transfrom left dataframe to right dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have tried melt, unstack and stack pandas functions but cannot understand how to implement them.

dataframe trasnformation and reformating:
[image: img]

Comment: It would be sure helpful if you post the Python code for the Pandas dataframe you want to transform and the code of what you have already tried explaining what exactly it is what you don't understand. Best upload also the image of what you want to achieve to your question here on stackoverflow instead of giving a link to it.

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the required transformation just can't be in a straightforward way done using Pandas functions because the source data structure does not fit well into the concept of a Pandas DataFrame and in addition to this it also does not contain the information about the required column names and columns the target DataFrame is expected to have along with the number of necessary duplicates of rows.

See the Python code illustrating the problem by providing dictionaries for the data tables:

```
import pandas as pd
pd_json_dict_src = {
    'Date':'2023-01-01',
    'Time':'14:00',
    'A':{
        'Intro':[
            {'FIB':'1.00'},
            {'DIB':'2.00'} ] },
    'B':{
        'Intro':[
            {'FIB':'3.00'},
            {'DIB':'4.00'} ] }
}
df_src = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd_json_dict_src)
print(df_src)
# -----------------------------------------------
pd_json_dict_tgt = {
    'Date':['2023-01-01','2023-01-01'],
    'Time':['14:00','14:00'],
    'Area':['A','B'],
    'Tech':['Intro','Intro'],
    'FIB' :['1.00','3.00'],
    'DIB' :['2.00','4.00']
}
df_tgt = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd_json_dict_tgt)
print(df_tgt)
```

prints

```
             Date  ...                                   B
Intro  2023-01-01  ...  [{'FIB': '3.00'}, {'DIB': '4.00'}]

[1 rows x 4 columns]
         Date   Time Area   Tech   FIB   DIB
0  2023-01-01  14:00    A  Intro  1.00  2.00
1  2023-01-01  14:00    B  Intro  3.00  4.00
```

I don't also see any easy to code automated way able to transform the by the dictionary defined source data structure into the data structure of the target dictionary.

In other words it seems that there is no straightforward and easy to code general way of flattening column-wise deep nested data structures especially when choosing Python Pandas as a tool for such flattening. At least as long as there is no other answer here proving me and this statement wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create the dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["2023-01-01","14:00",1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]])

            0      1     2    3    4    5
0  2023-01-01  14:00  1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00
```

Set the index columns:

```py
df = df.set_index([0,1]).rename_axis(["Date", "Time"])

                     2    3    4    5
Date       Time                     
2023-01-01 14:00  1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00
```

Create the multi-level columns:

```py
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("A", "Intro", "FIB"), ("A", "Intro", "DIB"), ("B", "Intro", "FIB"), ("B", "Intro", "DIB")], names=["Area", "Tech", ""])

Area                  A           B     
Tech              Intro       Intro     
                    FIB  DIB    FIB  DIB
Date       Time                       
2023-01-01 14:00   1.00 2.00   3.00 4.00
```

Use [stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) on levels "Area" and "Tech":

```py
df = df.stack(["Area","Tech"])

                             DIB  FIB
Date       Time  Area Tech           
2023-01-01 14:00 A    Intro 2.00 1.00
                 B    Intro 4.00 3.00
```

Reset index to create columns "Date" and "Time" and repeat their values:

```py
df = df.reset_index()

         Date   Time Area   Tech  DIB  FIB
0  2023-01-01  14:00    A  Intro 2.00 1.00
1  2023-01-01  14:00    B  Intro 4.00 3.00
```